# "geht" or "geht es"; nominative or accusative?

Tags: idiom, accusative, nominative

I want to translate the English sentence "Next weekend doesn't work / won't work" into German. Are either of the following correct German translations, and if so, is one of them preferred?

- (1) "Nächstes Wochenende geht nicht", or
- (2) "Nächstes Wochenende geht **es** nicht"?

(The bold font on "es" is just to point out the difference.)

And likewise, translating "The next day doesn't/won't work":

- (A) "Der nächste Tag geht nicht", or
- (B) "Der nächste Tag geht **es** nicht", or
- (C) "**Den** nächsten Tag geht nicht", or
- (D) "**Den** nächsten Tag geht **es** nicht"?

I would like to work out (assuming some of the above are correct) which objects (of "es", "next weekend", "the next day") are (translating as) nominative or accusative (note there's no dative appearing).

Finally, are there German translations of these English phrases which are more correct than any of those listed above?

Comment: Kommt auf den Kontext an, würde ich sagen, je nach dem, wie die Frage war, auf die das eine Antwort sein soll.

Comment: For sure the sentence (B) is wrong, however, introducing two nominatives (*Tag* and *es*) without a visible relation.

Answer (score 2):

"es" is a surface subject in all your cases, so it's always in the nominative case.

"Der nächste Tag" is obviously nominative case, "Den nächsten Tag" is accusative. As others have remarked, the accusative case is correct when using a noun phrase as a temporal expression, so you say

> Nächsten Freitag [temporal expression] geht es nicht.

but

> Der nächste Freitag [subject] geht nicht.

Therefore, "nächstes Wochenende" is nominative in your first example and accusative in the second one.